# Points $A,B,C$ lie on a circle with center $O$, radius $7$. The perpendicular bisector of $AB$ meets $BC$ at $P$ and $AC$ at $Q$. Find $OP \cdot OQ$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles, problem-solving

> Points $A,B,C$ lie on a circle centered at $O$ with radius $7$. The perpendicular bisector of $AB$ meets $BC$ at $P$ and $AC$ at $Q$. Find $OP \cdot OQ$ .

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

I thought about using Power of a Point but that did not help since $S$ does not lie on the circumference of the circle. The only information known is that the radius equals $7$, so I cannot use Pythagorean Theorem either. Joining $OA$,$OB$,$AP$ gives some congruent triangles, but I did not find a good way to use them.

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that $\angle PCO = 90-A$. Also $\angle AQP = 90-A$.

Thus $OC$ is tangent to circumcircle of $\triangle PCQ$ (by converse of alternate segment theorem).

So by power of point, $$OP \cdot OQ = OC^2 = r^2$$

---

Edit :

$\angle COA = 2B \Rightarrow \angle ACO = 90-B$

$\angle PCO = C - (90-B)=90-A$

Comment: Why are those $2$ angles $90 - A?$

Comment: Brilliant method(+1)

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Note
$$\angle OCP = \frac{180 - \angle BOC }2 = 90 - \angle A = \angle Q$$

Thus, the triangles COP and COQ are similar, yielding

$$OP\cdot OQ = OC^2 =49$$